# React hooks removing item from an array and add it to another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function ShoppingCart() {
  const classes = useStyle();
  const {
    productsList, filteredProductsList, setFilteredProductsList, setProductsList,
  } = useContext(productsContext);
  const [awaitingPaymentList, setAwaitingPaymentList] = useState([]);
  const [addedToCartList, setAddedToCartList] = useState([]);
 

  const addToCartHandler = useCallback((itemId) => {
    const awaitingPaymentListIds = awaitingPaymentList.map((item) => item.id);
    const isInAwaitingPaymentList = awaitingPaymentListIds.includes(itemId);

    isInAwaitingPaymentList ? setAddedToCartList([...addedToCartList, addedToCartList.push(awaitingPaymentList[awaitingPaymentList.findIndex((item) => item.id === itemId)])]) : setAddedToCartList([...addedToCartList]);

    isInAwaitingPaymentList
      ? setAwaitingPaymentList(awaitingPaymentList.splice(awaitingPaymentList.findIndex((item) => item.id === itemId), 1))
      : setAwaitingPaymentList([...awaitingPaymentList ])

    setProductsList(awaitingPaymentList);
  }, [addedToCartList, awaitingPaymentList, setProductsList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredProductsList(
      productsList.filter((product) => product.status === 'AWAITING_PAYMENT'),
    );
  }, [productsList, setFilteredProductsList, setFilteredProductsList.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAwaitingPaymentList(filteredProductsList);
  }, [filteredProductsList]);
```

I manage to delete the item from awaitingPaymentList and to add it into addedToCartList but looks like I am doing something wrong because it is adding the object, but the previous ones are replaced with numbers :). On the first click, the array is with one object inside with all data, but after each followed click is something like this => [1,2,3, {}].
When I console log addedToCartList outside addToCartHandler function it is showing an array: [1] :)))

Since there is some code I hope I am not going to receive a lot of negative comments like last time. And if it's possible, to give me a clue how to make it for all items to be transferred at once, because there will be a button to add all. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you provide a working CodePen or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line of code is causing issue:

```
isInAwaitingPaymentList
  ? setAddedToCartList([
      ...addedToCartList,
      addedToCartList.push(
        awaitingPaymentList[
          awaitingPaymentList.findIndex((item) => item.id === itemId)
        ]
      )
    ])
  : setAddedToCartList([...addedToCartList]);
```

[array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array that you are pushing into, this is likely where the incrementing element values are coming from. The `push` is also a state mutation.

It is not really clear what you want this code to do, but I think the `push` is unnecessary. Perhaps you meant to just append the last element into the new array you are building.

```
isInAwaitingPaymentList
  ? setAddedToCartList([
      ...addedToCartList, // <-- copy state
      awaitingPaymentList[ // <-- add new element at end
        awaitingPaymentList.findIndex((item) => item.id === itemId)
      ]
    ])
  : setAddedToCartList([...addedToCartList]);
```

## Suggestion

If you simply want to move an element from one array to another then `find` it in the first, then filter it from the first, and copy to the second if it was found & filtered.

```
const itemToMove = awaitingPaymentList.find(item => item.id === itemId);
setAwaitingPaymentList(list => list.filter(item => item.id !== itemId));
itemToMove && setAddedToCartList(list => [...list, { ...itemToMove }])
```

Comment: Yeap thank you very much I was wondering couple of hours, what I am doing wrong here. :)

Comment: I do not want to bother you again, but how should I make it to transfer all items at once :). Thank you for your time and help! Much appreciated!

Comment: @DragoJokera What all items are you speaking of?

Comment: I mean awaitingPaymentList to be removed and transferred at once to addedToCartList.

Comment: The suggestion you wrote above is to copy the element, but since I want to remove it from the first one, should I use splice or it is not necessary? Will it be copied and removed at the same time?

Comment: Drew Reese, now I noticed, that the code above, on the first click just creates an array, which is empty (very strange because it is transferred to the cart). So for example, if I have 10 items in the first array, when I add all of them in the second I will have only 9 items. Also when all the items are added inside the addedToCartList if I want to delete the last one, all are deleted and just the one that has been clicked remains (I am using the same code for deleting, because I want the items to be transferred again into the first list (awaitingPaymentList).

Comment: @DragoJokera The filter function removes the element from the first array. Can you provide a *running* code sandbox for this component? I don't think you need to wire up the context provider, but if you could mock the local component state and render this component I can take a look at how data is flowing through it. Perhaps you've more state mutation/update issues elsewhere. Here is my [codesandbox test](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-removing-item-from-an-array-and-add-it-to-another-array-vmkks)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide any code. I am fetching data from the server, and I am using filteredProducts, so only the ones, which are not paid to appear, the productList presents all the products. I checked your code, it is deleting the items, but in the console at the end inside the new array you got also only two objects.

Comment: @DragoJokera Are you trying to console log the state right after the update in the `addToCartHandler` function? This will only log the current state, not the enqueued state for the next render cycle. Try logging state in its own `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency. I added logging to my linked sandbox.

Comment: I found my mistake, everything was coming from one of the useEffect hooks, now it's working just fine. I am curious is it a good way to add all items like this: `const addAllToCartHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setAddedToCartList(awaitingPaymentList);
    setAwaitingPaymentList([]);
  }, [awaitingPaymentList]); `                                                                                       or there is some better way of transferring all items at once.

Comment: @DragoJokera Do you mean to take *all* the items from the `awaitingPaymentList` array and move them into the `addedToCartList` array? I don't think you really need to memoize this callback as you aren't returning a value and would always want the latest `awaitingPaymentList` value anyway. You also wouldn't be able to have `awaitingPaymentList` in the dependency array either as the function calls `setAwaitingPaymentList`, this would cause render looping. Otherwise, yes, I think you could move the array from one state variable to the other as an atomic action.

Comment: It was not a problem to move all at once and also it was not a problem to have awaitingPaymentList as a dependency it did not cause an infinite loop. But the problem, that I have at the moment is, if I add first a couple of items and then I decide to transfer all at once with this button for transferring all (the code that I wrote above) it deletes all the previous items, which has been added and just set the state of setAddedToCartList with the remaining items from the awaitingPaymentList ... :( Any idea how it should be done?

Comment: What I mean if I have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and first I just add 5,6 for example and then I press Add All , in the cart I will have all the items except 5 and 6 :)

Comment: @DragoJokera Where are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10? You add *just* 5 and 6 to `awaitingPaymentList`, then click "add all", and you want 5 & 6 moved to the `addedToCartList`? Or are you asking something different?

Comment: In the awaitingPaymentList i have 1,2,3,4,5... then I use the function addToCartHandler (just to transfer a couple of items e.g 2 and 3), so in addedToCartList I will have 2 and 3. But after that, if I just decide that I need all the items and I press a button for adding all (but in this case I will have only the remaining items in the awaitingPaymentList(1,4,5)) And this will set my addedToCartList to 1,4,5 and this 2 and 3 will be gone. Inside addedToCartList after clicking Add All there should be 2,3,1,4,5 all the items that I have at the very beginning.

Comment: Hopefully, you understand what I mean :)

Comment: @DragoJokera Ok, so instead of completely overwriting `addedToCartList` with the contents of `awaitingPaymentList` you need shallow copy the *current* contents of `addedToCartList` first, then shallow copy the contents of `awaitingPaymentList`. I.e something like `const addAllToCart = () => { setAddedToCartList(cart => [...cart, ...awaitingPaymentList]); setAwaitingPaymentList([]); };`.

Comment: Yeap, that is working fine, I tried it but I just made a shallow copy of the current content of addedToCartList and the awaitingPaymentList without making a shallow copy of it. `addAllToCart = () => { setAddedToCartList(cart => [...cart, awaitingPaymentList])`. Thanks once again.

Comment: @DragoJokera That is ok, but I think you should really get into the habit/practice of copying references into new state objects in react as this helps avoid the state/object mutation class of bugs.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I am just a newbie, just making my first steps in JS and React